# How do proteins perform their function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, biophysics, molecules, interactions

Let's, for example, take a ribosome. It is an enzyme that is in turn just a molecule that must follow the laws of physics.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it can be looked upon as a molecular machine made up of several pieces. What exactly makes those pieces work together?

Why does the ribosome bind to a strand of RNA? Is it just the shape and electric charge or is it something more? Once the ribosome is bound to a piece of RNA, how does it move?

In a way, I'm looking for the "ghost in the machine". I'm interested in molecules in general, not just ribosomes. What is it that, on a level of single atoms, makes molecules "alive" - move, assemble a protein, etc. ?

Let me give a hypothetical example:

Imagine a strand of carbons. Also imagine that there exists a molecule that can move along this strand. How would it do it? What forces would move it along this strand? Is it electromagnetism? Would gravity be involved to a significant degree? What effect would shape have?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is biology not physics

Comment: Its a good and interesting question, but this is the wrong place for it.

Comment: @JohnRennie If you think that this is a biology question, I have not explained myself properly

Comment: Good luck writing the Hamiltonian for a protein.  That's why this is a biology question: there's no value to trying to describe the quantum-level operation.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft is there really no way to explain how a molecule can move on/along another molecule without writing out a Hamiltonian?

Comment: Of course there are ways to explain these things, but they don't start from first principles. That's what the biologists do and they use chemistry to tackle these questions. The only place where physics proper comes in is by giving them the tools to measure these interactions dynamically, e.g. with ultrafast x-ray crystallography. Like everybody else said: this question doesn't belong into physics.

Comment: please, before closing this question consider what is discussed [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/should-biophysics-fork?cb=1) in meta. Closing it, you close more and more the door to experts bio-physicist who could give great contributions, improving this site.

Comment: @CuriousOne With all the respect, limiting biophysics to x-ray crystallography is really too narrow. Molecular motors (like the ribosome) are subject of intense research led by many physicists, from developing techniques to measure their activity (e.g. optical tweezers) to theoretical modeling their mechano-chemical cycles. really, make this site a favor, leave this question open (see [this meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/should-biophysics-fork?cb=1)).

Comment: I agree... we can provide the tools, but we aren't providing the theory or the systems, to begin with.

Comment: @CuriousOne, there is a _lot_ that can be said about this topic. For example, look at [this](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.158101) physics paper from last year; you can get a bound on how reliably a molecule motor can work from just thermodynamics. This exact question is the point of my current physics research project; if this is open in a few months, I'll come back and write a fantastic answer.

Comment: @knzhou: By the same argument you can have a bunch of semiconductor engineers take over physics.SE... there is a heck of a lot more physics in semiconductor manufacturing (all of it is physics, really), than there is in biology. We don't let that happen, either.

Comment: @CuriousOne: but the math involved here is just plain old thermodynamics. Do you not count that as a field of physics?

Comment: It's true that thermo doesn't start from first principles (i.e. microscopic modeling) but I've always seen it counted as a field of physics more than anything else.

Comment: @knzhou: The math involved in semiconductor engineering is that used in thermodynamics, quantum mechanics, atomic physics, solid state physics, optics, electron optics, ion beam optics, nuclear physics etc.. The semiconductor engineers have it.

Comment: @CuriousOne then what is physics SE good for?

Comment: @Andrey: Physics. Physics is not an endless discipline. One could argue that chemistry is applied thermodynamics and quantum theory. That's true, but we still don't like to stand at the bench and we let the chemists do that. If you have read the chemical literature then you will know why: it takes a totally different set of skills to be an average chemist than it takes to be a good physicist. The same is true for biology. I happen to work with life sciences people a lot, these days, and 99% of the time I have no clue what they are talking about, I do not even know the basics.

Comment: Its all thermodynamics, entropy increases with thesr

Comment: @user209347: ... where your last word 'thesr' is to emphasize the entropy increase? :)

Comment: This question (v3) is (besides being off-topic) too broad. It currently contains around 10 sub-questions.

Comment: ... These processes as they are thermodynically the optimal way to go, nature is determined so its the flow of time

Comment: I have opened [a meta-question on the range and limits of biophysics](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7386/what-are-the-boundaries-of-biophysics-on-physics-se) on [physics.se], which I suppose to be of interest to many of the commenters here. Come have your say in the place it will matter most.